# Laravel multiple array

Tags: php, xml, laravel

I have `xml` export file where I need to loop data several time inside each other but not sure how it can be done.

## Logic

1. Loop products
2. Loop products relationships
3. Get product and it's relationships data into variables
4. Export the file which is include information of product and it's relationships

## Code

Before we get to code it's good to mention for sake of readability I made my xml code shorter with 1 relationship sample only. If it works then I will take care of the rest inputs myself. (I just need help to fix 1 variable the rest I'll do...) `relationship part commented`

```
public function export(Request $request) {

$products = Product::orderby('id', 'desc')->with([
    'allBarcodes',
    'allBarcodes.transits',
    'allBarcodes.outerTransits',
    'allBarcodes.outlet',
    'existBarcodes',
    'existBarcodes.transits',
    'existBarcodes.outerTransits',
    'existBarcodes.outlet',
    'soldBarcodes',
    'soldBarcodes.transits',
    'soldBarcodes.outerTransits',
    'soldBarcodes.outlet',
    'images',
])->get();


foreach($products as $product) {
    $array = [
        "TRANSACTIONS" => [
            '_attributes' => [
                'OnError' => 'CONTINUE'
            ],
            'SALESINVOICE' => [
                '_attributes' => [
                    'operation' => 'Add',
                    'REQUESTID' => '1'
                ],
                'TRANSACTIONID' => '260363',
                'ITEMLINE' => [
                    '_attributes' => [
                        'operation' => 'Add'
                    ],
                    'KeyID' => '1',
                    'ITEMNO' => 'Z4B53A-TEST',
                    'QUANTITY' => '1',
                    'ITEMUNIT' => 'UNT',
                    'UNITRATIO' => '1',
                    'ITEMRESERVED1' => '',
                    'ITEMRESERVED2' => '',
                    'ITEMRESERVED3' => '',
                    'ITEMRESERVED4' => '',
                    'ITEMRESERVED5' => '',
                    'ITEMRESERVED6' => '',
                    'ITEMRESERVED7' => '',
                    'ITEMRESERVED8' => '',
                    'ITEMRESERVED9' => '',
                    'ITEMRESERVED10' => '',
                    'ITEMOVDESC' => $product->name,
                    'UNITPRICE' => $product->price,
                    'ITEMDISCPC' => '',
                    'TAXCODES' => '',
                    'GROUPSEQ' => '',
                    'SOSEQ' => '',
                    'BRUTOUNITPRICE' => $product->price,
                    'WAREHOUSEID' => 'PS',
                    'QTYCONTROL' => '0',
                    'DOSEQ' => '',
                ],
                'INVOICENO' => 'POINS-001', // this value comes from relationship ('allBarcodes.transits') column (tansNu) "$product->allBarcodes->transits->tansNu"
            ],
        ]
    ];
}


$filename = 'data.xml';
$result = ArrayToXml::convert($array, [
    'rootElementName' => 'NMEXML',
    '_attributes' => [
        'EximID'=> "12551",
        'BranchCode'=> "1450645381",
        'ACCOUNTANTCOPYID'=> ""
    ]
]);
Storage::disk('local')->put($filename, $result);
$fullPath = url('exports', $filename);

return response()->json([
    'data' => $fullPath
]);
}
```

#### Screenshot

[image: one]

## Explanation

What I need is to get `'INVOICENO'` value from `$product->allBarcodes->transits` (it's array / could be null) then after looping this relationship get the column `tansNu` value as of `INVOICENO`.

**any ideas?**

## Update

Model relationships

`Product.php`

```
public function allBarcodes()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Barcode::class, 'product_id', 'id');
}
```

`Barcode.php`

```
public function product()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
}
public function transits()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Transit::class, 'barcode_id', 'id');
}
```

`Transit.php`

```
public function barcode()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Barcode::class);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `tansNu` is a string, you should be able to retrieve the array of `tansNu` from `$product` using some handy [collection methods](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-flatmap). For this to work you must have the relationships eager loaded (which you have in your code)

```
// in your $product loop you can get the tansNu list like so
$invoiceNoCollection = collect([$product])->flatMap(function($p){
        return $p->allBarcodes;
    })->flatMap(function($b){
        return $b->transits->pluck('tansNu');
    });
```

At this point `$invoiceNoCollection` should hold all the `tansNu` of the `$product`. You didn't specify what you want the output to be like but i'd assume you want it to be [unique](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-unique), [not null](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-filter), and as an array which you can achieve like this

```
$invoiceNoArray = $invoiceNoCollection->filter()->unique()->toArray();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for response, the output of `tansNu` is string as you predicted but having value or not is depend on having `allBarcodes` for example if product has `barcodes (allBarcodes)` for sure each of them will have `tansNu` but if product doesn't have `allBarcodes` then `tansNu` will be null as well.

Comment: @mafortis The code should still run fine even if `allBarcodes` is null. did you get an error? if you call `->filter()` like in the second code block then it will get rid of all the nulls you get, so you will just get an empty array

Comment: just turn on system give me several minutes i will test your code... :)

Comment: I was getting this error `syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR), expecting ')'` and i edit your code to `$invoiceNoCollection = $product->flatMap(function($p){
return $p->allBarcodes;
})->flatMap(function($b){
return $b->transits->pluck('tansNu');
});` added `)` then i get this error `Call to undefined method App\Product::flatMap()`

Comment: Ok I got it now, before my relationship was `belongsTo` now that I changed it to `hasMany` it prints empty array. But I need each transit separately perhaps i need to loop my products more?

Comment: should i loop my product based on `transits`?

Comment: that's the thing, the `INVOICENO` aren't the same that's why i need them as string and not array in my xml

Comment: yes, but i figure something, I played with your code and in all conditions it return empty array! I've commented all my codes just to check output of your code specifically and results of `$p->allBarcodes` and `return $b->transits->pluck('tansNu');` both return empty array. while my data exist in database.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216460/discussion-between-helioarch-and-mafortis).